# Append id to router-link in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm running Vue.js and have a `for`-loop and a trying to generate links with `href` like `/car/xyz`:

```
<router-link to="/car/+ car.id">{{ car.id }}</router-link>
```

But it fails to render correctly, as I guess I'm appending the `car.id` wrong to the `to` value?

Answer (score 12):

Just replace `to` with `:to` and format value as a string:

```
<router-link :to="'/car/' + car.id">{{ car.id }}</router-link>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#to); the recommended way is to bind the path as an object.

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'user', params: { userId: 123 }}">User</router-link>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work `<router-link :to="{ name: 'car', params: { id: car.id }}">{{ car.id }}</router-link>`

Comment: Are you getting any errors? How does your `routes` array look?

Comment: { path: '/car/:id', component: CAR, props: true }

Comment: @AlfredBalle If you use this option, the route has to define the name property.

Comment: Exactly, so `{ path: '/car/:id', component: CAR, name: 'car', props: true }` should work ;)

Comment: It doesn't, simply renders as `<a href="/sim/:id">...` So id is not replaced with, well, `id`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to write like this...

```
<router-link :to="`/car/${car.id}`">{{ car.id }}</router-link>
```

**for template literals:**
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

**for binding in vue:**
https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/class-and-style

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).